SSRS Powershell Rest API "The given key was not present in the dictionary"
I am trying to create a subscription to a report via SSRS Rest API 2.0, but I am getting the error "The given key was not present in the dictionary".
I am on SSRS Version 15.0.8863.19101 locally and deploying to version 15.0.8270.42049.
$ownerName='domain\user'
$reportName='Report Name'
$targetPath='/Reports'
 $CreateReportSubscriptionJSON = '
            {
                "Owner": "'+$ownerName.Replace('\','\\')+'",
                "Description": "'+$reportName+'",
                "IsDataDriven": true,
                "Report": "'+$targetPath+'/'+$reportName+'",
                "EventType": "TimedSubscription",
                "Schedule": {
                    "ScheduleID": null,
                    "Definition": {
                        "StartDateTime": "2024-07-17T02:00:00-04:00",
                        "EndDateSpecified": false,
                        "EndDate": "1901-02-01T00:00:00-05:00",
                        "Recurrence": {
                            "MinuteRecurrence": {
                                "MinutesInterval": 120
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "DeliveryExtension": "Report Server FileShare",
                "ExtensionSettings": {
                    "Extension": "Report Server FileShare",
                    "ParameterValues": [
                        { 
                        "Name": "FILENAME",
                           "Value": "Filename",
                           "IsValueFieldReference": true
                         },
                        { 
                        "Name": "PATH",
                           "Value": "Path",
                           "IsValueFieldReference": true
                         },
                        { 
                        "Name": "RENDER_FORMAT",
                           "Value": "PDF",
                           "IsValueFieldReference": false
                         } ,
                        { 
                        "Name": "WRITEMODE",
                           "Value": "OverWrite",
                           "IsValueFieldReference": false
                         },
                        { 
                        "Name": "FILEEXTN",
                           "Value": "False",
                           "IsValueFieldReference": false
                         },
                        { 
                        "Name": "DEFAULTCREDENTIALS",
                           "Value": "True",
                           "IsValueFieldReference": false
                         }
 
                    ]
             }
             ,
             "ParameterValues": [
                        ...
                     ],
                "DataQuery": {
                    "CommandText":  "EXEC XXX",
                    "Timeout": 300
                    }
                    ,
                "DataSource": {
                    "IsReference": true,
                    "Name": "/Data Sources/Primary",
                    "Path": "/Data Sources/Primary"
                    }
            }
            '

The data source exists.  The report exists. The following is setting up and attempting to invoke a REST API call, but I get the following error...
$catalogItemsUri = 'https://localhost/reports/api/v2.0'
$CreateReportSubscriptionURI = "$catalogItemsUri/subscriptions"
$CreateReportSubscriptionResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $CreateReportSubscriptionURI -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-16' -Body $CreateReportSubscriptionJSON -Credential $creds -UseBasicParsing

Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error":{
    "code":"2","message":"The given key was not present in the dictionary."
  }
}

In the ReportingServicesService Log, the following appears when I attempt the REST call..
WARN: Data-driven subscription query with SchemaOnly flag did not return schema information. Re-executing as full query.

What am I doing wrong?  Is it NOT possible to create a subscription for a report this way.  I even used Google Developer tools to capture the appropriate JSON for when creating the report that was submitted via the UI and it doesn't work.
